# Visual Studio 08 will not allow me to create Silverlight project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight

So I installed the Silverlight 3 SDK a while ago and VS worked fine.  Yesterday I unisntalled the Silverlight 2 SDK.  Then when I tried to create a Silverlight project I got an error stating

```
You need to install the silverlight 2 sdk before creating a silverlight project
```

Why?  Is this required?  I unisntalled the Silverlight 3 SDK and reinstalled, same error occurs.  I then uninstalled everything related to silverlight (Silverlight 3 SDK, tools, and VS 2008 SP1) and re-installed.  Now when i go to select a new Silverlight project, there are no options for creating a project, library, etc.

How do i correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you installing the SDK or the Silverlight Tools?  The SDK knows nothing (ostensibly) about Visual Studio.  You need to install the Tools which will include the SDK to enable creation of Silverlight apps in VS 2008.  See [Getting Started](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/).

Comment: im an idiot.  I confused the Silverlight Tools with the Silverlight Toolkit.

Comment: Ah..umm yes I can see how that could happen: Silverlight __Tool__ s, Software Development __Kit__ and Silverlight __Toolkit__, it all seems to blur into one thing ;)